# .Net Maui HttpClient GetStringAsync() slow only on physical device

Tags: c#, android, ios, dotnet-httpclient, maui

I am using HttpClient service for simple GetStringAsync() request. While running the app on android emulator, avarage response time is less than ~0.5sec. The problem appears on a physical devices where response is 3 to even 9 seconds.

Because at the same moment, the app have another running service in background (simple while (true) loop downloading other data every 5 sec) also using HttpClient, I've tried disabling it but after that, response time is only ~0.2 secs faster (I also have no idea why it have any impact on other requests since I am reusing the same HttpClient, not creating new one).

- I also tried disabling firewall on my host computer but didn't
  worked. Using HttpClientFactory is not solving problem either.

I wonder if there is any different way to download string from url for .Net maui or am I using it in wrong way or should I add any options to my HttpClient?

HttpClient:

```
public static HttpClient _httpclient;
```

and

```
_hhtpclient = new HttpClient();
```

Request:

```
var jsoN = await _httpclient.GetStringAsync(@"http://192.168.0.209:8032/getStatus?Id=" +id);
            if (jsoN != null)
            {
                var status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Status>(jsoN);
                return status ;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
```

Devices i tested on:

- Samsung a73 (Android 12.0)
- Huwawei Nova Y90 (EMUI 12)

My internet speed (tested on host computer):

> DOWNLOAD 295.03 Mb/s | UPLOAD 30.70 Mb/s

Comment: is your device using WiFi or cell?  Is your PC using the same WiFi, or a physical ethernet?  Is your PC also the server you are downloading from?  Is your service already running and not dormant when you test?

Comment: Phones are running on wifi, pc is connected to the internet with ethernet, yes the same pc is also the place where i store the data and service is always running during the tests.

Comment: have you tested connecting from the browser **on the device** to your server?

Comment: Yes, works fine.

Comment: Make a new app. Add minimum code needed to do GetStringAsync, WITHOUT complication of any other threads, or other uses of HttpClient. Test its performance. Much better, right? If so, then there is an issue with *other* code; something is "starving" the app's attempt to process GetStringAsync. Note that ***first* call might be slow;** once your app's HttpClient is "warmed up", should be able to do *second* call (using same HttpClient instance) quickly. But first call shouldn't take multiple seconds. For test, don't call while first page UI is initializing.